# parse error before '*' token

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

```
const EPGState* NewEPGState[] =
{
    &bootupState,
    &standbyState,
    &watchtvState,
    &guideState,
    &settingsState,
    &easState,
    &diagnosticsState
};
```

What is wrong in this code? I am getting an error parse error before '*' token
Your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: may be EPGState is not a valid type?

Comment: show the declaration of EPGState and other variables you have used in the code.

Comment: can you posy whole source?

Comment: I bet it's a `struct`.

Comment: Maybe missing semi-colon `;` at end of _previous_ statement?

Answer (score 0):

Check which version of the compiler are you using , This code compiles well on
g++ version 4.1.2 20071124.
but fails when compiled with gcc

I assume you have defined class/struct EPGState correctly and all the variables used below are of same type i.e EPGState.

```
class EPGState
{
};
int main()
{ 
    EPGState bootupState,standbyState;
   const EPGState* NewEPGState[] =
   {
       &bootupState,
       &standbyState
   };
}
```

Are you getting "parse Error" at the compilation step or at run time.
This is not clear from the question.

I written some sample code to test.

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int *ac[]={&a,&b};
    return 0;
}
```

- Above code fails on gcc and compiles on g++.
- gcc version 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)

  `/tmp/cc6829sJ.o: In function __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
  test1.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to std::ios_base::Init::Init()`

Comment: I don't think at runtime there can be a parse error before the `*` token. Except the program would parse its own source code...

Comment: @glglgl Oh yes, It cannot happen in the above listed code, Except there are some other "*"s inside files which are being parsed by given program.

Comment: `class`? `iostream`? C?

Comment: Let the author unfold the mystery whether it is class or struct , C or c++

Answer (score 0):

You probaly have

```
struct EPGState
{
  ...


struct EPGState bootupState = 
{
  ...
```

somewhere.

Then is shall be

```
const struct EPGState * NewEPGState[] =
{
    &bootupState,
    ...
```